# How to use cs script in unityscript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have C# scripts in my Unity project.
I want to use it in my JS script. 
But I can't make any reference to a class in the C# script.

How to do that?

Comment: The correct tag for Unity is [unity3d]. Please make sure to use this tag. If you don't most of us might miss your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that at compile time different compilers are used for the different languages. So they have no knowledge of each other's existence. There is a way around it by [considering the steps in which Unity compiles code](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html).

Code in a folder named Plugins for example (as well as Standard Assets" and "Pro Standard Assets") is compiled before code in regular folders. So if you want to call your C# code using UnityScript, put your C# code in a folder name Plugins within your assets.

If you then keep your UnityScript code in a regular folder, once it will be compiled the C# code should already be compiled and available.